# Error while copying files from source to destination java

Tags: java, nio

```
//original file
Path original = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Laksahan\Desktop\\bg.jpg"); 
File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Laksahan\\Desktop\\bg.jpg");

// new file
Path destination = Paths.get("C:\\Program Files\\Tour v0.1\\image\\"+f.getName()); 
try {
   Files.copy(original, destination, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
} catch (IOException x) {
   x.printStackTrace();
}
```

i tried above method to copy files, it wont work and it prints this error

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Laksahan\Desktop\bg.jpg -> C:\Program Files\Tour v0.1\image\bg.jpg
```

please help

Comment: I tried the same code it worked for me.
Since you are doing it in the C drive inside Program Files there may be permission issues.

Comment: @Mukesh S i did check it on C:\\ but it says the same error

Comment: @Mukesh it worked on D: drive

Answer (score 19):

Java 7's NIO **will not create a folder if it doesn't exist when using** `Files.copy()`.

The best you can do is check for the folder and create it if it doesn't exist before you call `copy`.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
Path original = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Laksahan\\Desktop\\bg.jpg");
```

instead of

```
Path original = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Laksahan\Desktop\\bg.jpg");
```

---

Create a folder programmatically for example -

```
Path from = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Laksahan\\Desktop\\bg.jpg"); 
Path to = Paths.get("C:\\Program Files\\Tour v0.1\\image\\"); 
Path destination;

File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Laksahan\\Desktop\\bg.jpg");

if (!Files.exists(to)) {
   try {
      Files.createDirectories(to);
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
   }

   destination = Paths.get(to.toString() + "\\" + f.getName());
   try {
      Files.copy(from, destination, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
   } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException faee) {
      faee.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
       ioe.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: That was probably just a typo. `\D` is not a valid escape sequence and therefore the code would not have compiled.